# Sets of "Isolated" Cardinals

Tags: reference-request, set-theory, cardinals, infinitary-combinatorics

Let $C\neq\emptyset$ be a set of infinite cardinals with the property that NO member of $C$ occurs as the supremum of strictly smaller members of $C$. So the cardinals in $C$ are sort of "isolated".

I am wondering if there is a name for such sets somewhere in literature, and where in mathematics they occur "naturally", if at all.

Comment: When studying partition relations in the context of determinacy, it is useful to look at sets of ordinals whose increasing enumerations are everywhere discontinuous in your sense. Kleinberg's book and some papers by Steve Jackson should suggest what terminology to adopt.

Answer (score 1):

It is consistent with ZFC that the *regular cardinals* - those which cannot be written as a "small" union of "small" cardinals - form such a class. Under this condition, of course, "regular" is the same as "successor," but regularity might seem a more natural property.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for successor cardinals.  They are all regular, so cannot be written as the sup of any smaller set.  By contrast limit cardinals like $\aleph_\omega$ can be written as the sup of smaller cardinals.  It doesn't seem natural to consider sets like your $C$, as $\aleph_\omega$ could be in it as long as there are only finitely many smaller cardinals in the set.